# Google translate, voice feature is not working

Tags: sound, chromium, microphone

Voice feature (mic) in google translate is not working in chromium. When I clicked on mic button, record looks like it started, but after 0.5 second it stopped.

```
Version 80.0.3987.87 (Official Build) Built on Ubuntu , running on Ubuntu 18.04 (64-bit)
```

And question, is there some plugin for chromium or app for Ubuntu?
For translation online based on incoming voice stream, for example when you call on hangouts.

Thanks.